# Error: $rootScope:infdig after migration from angular 1.4 to 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-1.5

After migration from angular 1.4 to 1.5 'Error: $rootScope:infdig ' is apeared.

There were some usages of `ng-init` in templates but their removing does not help.

Problems occurs when `accordion-group` from `ui-bootstrap` (v.0.13.1) is used after second and next visits of same route template.

Maybe someone encounter same problem with using this version of `ui-bootstrap` (cannot be updated to higher version for now) or know some known issues related to such problem in angular 1.5

Just to notice that all worked fine in angular v.1.4.10

Update1:
I found one possible solution to fix infdig error which helps in one of my cases but not for all.

Under the `accordion-group` was used custom directive with `templateUrl`. After replacing `templateUrl` with `template` error is disappeared.

Hope this will help somebody

Comment: Please add your code or Plunker

Comment: sorry, but I cannot add the production code. I just want to ask some advice or maybe somebody counter with same problem

Comment: I have created similar situation inside Plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/n4noi1DQYLrlX7fQIpSZ/ but I cannot reproduce my issue there. Looks like there are more watchers in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [infinite digest documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) and debug keeping examples from doc in mind: it is likely you will find where — and why — infinite loop occurs

Comment: after removing using of `accordion` directive from my templates all works fine